# Entity Framework Remove One-To-Zero-One Replationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I stuck on the issue with deleting Relationship objects from db. Everything works fine on my localdb, but it throws an error on when i run it on server.
I have followings model:

```
public class Article
{
    public Article()
    {
        Paragraphs = new List<Paragrap>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime PostedDate { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool isPosted { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Paragrap> Paragraphs { get; set; }
}

public class Paragrap
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ArticleID { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    //[ForeignKey("PictureRefID")]
    //public int PictureID { get; set; }
    public virtual Picture Picture { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ArticleID")]
    public virtual Article Article { get; set; }
}

public class Picture
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Paragrap")]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string PictureURL { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual Paragrap Paragrap{ get; set; }
}
```

And when im trying to delete Article, I also want to delete Paragraphs and Pictures. If I understand correctly the issue lies on deleting Pictures from DB, but I may be mistaken. Here is Delete method:

```
        public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Article article = db.Articles.Find(id);
        List<Paragrap> ParToDelete = new List<Paragrap>();
        List<Picture> PicToDelete = new List<Picture>();
        List<Ingreadient> IngToDelete = new List<Ingreadient>();
        try
        {
            var p = from c in db.Paragraps
                    where c.ArticleID == id
                    select c;
            ParToDelete.AddRange(p);

            foreach (var item in p)
            {
                var i = item.ID;
                PicToDelete.Add(db.Pictures.Find(i));
            }
            foreach (var item in article.Ingreadient)
            {
                IngToDelete.Add(item);
            }
            db.Paragraps.RemoveRange(ParToDelete);
            db.Pictures.RemoveRange(PicToDelete);
            db.Articles.Remove(article);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            Article art = await db.Articles.FindAsync(id);
            return View(article);
        }
    }
```

The Paragraph ID and Picture ID are 1 to 1 in db(server).
Does anyone has any idea what is the problem?!

**UPDATE**
After more debugging I it seems like issue is in db.Pictures.Find(i) method. I checked Picture DB ID and they are the same as value passed to method.

Comment: A much better approach would be to put an `IsActive` flag on the object and just set it to `false`.  Soft deleting like this is a much better practice in the long run. Unwinding foreign key relations *sucks*.

Comment: Try deleting the pictures before deleting the paragraphs. When you delete the paragraph you have a foreign key on the picture which is then invalid.

Comment: Deleting pictures before paragraph didnt work. I am mostly confused because on localdb everything works out, but not on server

Comment: Is your local db an exact match of the server?  If the columns on the tables differ then that could explain the difference.

Comment: server db and local db are excaclty the same with no diffrence

Comment: And in both cases you are attempting to delete the same exact item?

Comment: No, i have diffrent entries on server

Comment: Then the difference is in the foreign keys.  Some entity on the server has a foreign key attached which is not present on the item you are attempting to delete locally.  Thus you hit the foreign key exception on the server but not locally.

Comment: If you want a better test case then you need to make a backup of the server db (if possible) and load it into your local sql instance.

Comment: I checked and all foreign on server (Pictures and Paragraphs) do exists and are 1-1.

Comment: Seed you local db with an example where you have all three, an Article which has Paragraphs and at least one of those paragraphs has a Picture.  Then try your code locally for that entity.  It would be best to have an exact copy of the server db but I know that isn't always possible.

Comment: Did it multiple times to find out if the error will happend on localdb. But it didnt. Everythink works fine on localdb, but not on server. I even deleted all entries (tryed both, on local and server db - just in case) and still have the same issue

Comment: You do not use flunt API?

Comment: No I dont. Everything is done with DataAnnotations

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is clean solution, but at least it is working now. The issue was in db.Picture.Find() method, what did throw me an error. The workaround what i used was to get All Pictures to a list (what worked for some reason) and sort them manually out

```
var p = from c in db.Paragraps
                where c.ArticleID == id
                select c;
        ParToDelete.AddRange(p);
        var Test = db.Pictures.ToList();
        foreach (var item in p)
        {
            foreach(var obj in Test)
                if(item.ID == obj.ID)
                      PicToDelete(obj);
        }
        foreach (var item in article.Ingreadient)
        {
            IngToDelete.Add(item);
        }
        db.Paragraps.RemoveRange(ParToDelete);
        db.Pictures.RemoveRange(PicToDelete);
        db.Articles.Remove(article);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
```